# getting "Too Many Initializer Values" error in 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

```
void Data::Paramters()
    
{
    for (int i = 0; i < I; i++)
    {
        mc[i] = new int[K];
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            mc[i][k] = {{1, 0, 2, 3, 5},{ 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 }, { 4, 3, 4, 1, 3 }, { 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 } };
        }
    }
}
```

getting "Too Many Initializer Values" error in starting of **{** 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 }
where I=5 and K=4

Comment: mc[i][k] refers to a single 2D array element, while you're trying to assign a whole 2D array.

Comment: @Salvage I'm pretty sure `mc[i][k]` refers to a single 1D array element, i.e., a single `int`.

Comment: If only we knew that for certain.

Comment: @JohnFilleau An element is fundamentally the same, no matter the dimension of the array it's in. But that's just arguing about semantics I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The initializer is for a 4x5 2D matrix, so you should just write:

```
enum { I = 4, K = 5 };

int mc[I][K] = { { 1, 0, 2, 3, 5 },
                 { 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 },
                 { 4, 3, 4, 1, 3 },
                 { 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 } };
```

Comment: Probably want to be using `constexpr` over macros.

Comment: @Salvage: indeed, but I am trying to keep the source as simple as possible :)

Comment: And that's a noble goal, but I have to admit the enum hack is probably more complex and idiosyncratic than the features "modern" C++11 provides. ^^

Comment: What would be the current idiom to define `I` and `K` these days? I am not familiar with *modern* C++ constructions... I gave up on it after ingurgitating the [Annotated C++ Reference Manual](https://www.stroustrup.com/arm.html) back in 1990 :)

Comment: Slightly depends on the context, inside classes and functions you'd want to use `static constexpr std::size_t I = 4;` and everywhere else you can just omit the `static` as `constexpr` implies `const` which implies internal linkage at namespace scope.
Yeah, C++ has changed a ton over the years (I wasn't there to witness it, just started learning when C++17 was around!), but I think in the large majority of cases it did change for the better. :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `mc[i][k]` has the type `int`. It is not an array.

So this assignment statement

```
mc[i][k] = {{1, 0, 2, 3, 5},{ 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 }, { 4, 3, 4, 1, 3 }, { 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 } };
```

does not make a sense.

If `K` is a constant expression then you can allocate and initialize the two-dimensional array the following way

```
int ( *mc )[K] = new int[I][K]
{ 
    { 1, 0, 2, 3, 5 },
    { 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 }, 
    { 4, 3, 4, 1, 3 }, 
    { 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 } 
};
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t K = 5;
    size_t I = 4;

    int ( *mc )[K] = new int[I][K]
    {
        { 1, 0, 2, 3, 5 },
        { 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 },
        { 4, 3, 4, 1, 3 },
        { 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < I; i++ )
    {
        for (const auto &item : mc[i])
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 2 3 5
4 2 2 1 3
4 3 4 1 3
3 5 6 4 2
```

Comment: Why is `I` not `const`?

Comment: @chqrlie Because it is unimportant.

Comment: @chqrlie Because variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: OK so `K` must be a constant expression, but not `I`. And defining `const size_t K = 5;` make `K` a constant expression in C++, whereas it does not in C, but C supports VLAs so it does not matter. Subtile differences :)

Comment: Is there a way to change `for ( size_t i = 0; i < I; i++ )` to something more trendy like `for (const auto &item : mc[i])` ?

Comment: @chqrlie For pointers functions begin and end are undefined.

Comment: Why would this not work: `for (const auto &row : mc) { for (const auto &item : row) ...`

Comment: @chqrlie As I have written for pointers ranges are undefined because pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single object or the first element of an array.

Comment: What would the type of `row` be in `for (const auto &row : mc)`?

Comment: @chqrlie If mc is a two dimensional array then the type will be const int ( & )[K]

Comment: OK, I get it: `mc` is not a 2D array, it is a pointer to an array of 1D arrays.